# List does not exist when trying to startworkflowonlistitem from CSOM

Tags: 2013, workflow, permissions, client-object-model

Using SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 Standard.

I believe this is an issue with permissions. When trying to start a workflow on a staging server, the following exception happens (as shown in UlsViewer).

```
Exception occured in scope Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.StartWorkflowOnListItem. Exception=System.ArgumentException:       List does not exist.      The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.       ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException:       List does not exist.      The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.           -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.ItemByInternalName(String strInternalName, Boolean bThrowException)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetListById(Guid uniqueID, Boolean bThrowException)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.StartWorkflowOnListItem(WorkflowSubscription subscription, Int32 itemId, IDictionary`2 payload)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceServiceServerStub.StartWorkflowOnListItem_MethodProxy(WorkflowInstanceService target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceServiceServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
```

The relevant code is the following:

```
var wfServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(ctx, ctx.Web);
var workflowDeploymentService = wfServicesManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService();
var wfSubscriptionService = wfServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
var wfSubscriptions = wfSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptions();
ctx.Load(wfSubscriptions, wfSubs => wfSubs.Where(wfSub => wfSub.Name == "Someuniqname"));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var wfSubscription = wfSubscriptions.First();
var wfInstanceService = wfServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();
var startParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
wfInstanceService.StartWorkflowOnListItem(wfSubscription, folioId, startParameters);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The IIS Application Pool is running as the same user account as the SharePoint App Pool, which happens to be a system account. I don't know if that could be an issue (I don't think so?), but just pointing it out.

EDIT:

Ok, for some reason, when I added and installed the .WSP, and I attached the Workflow to the list, there are two different Workflow Subscriptions returned by the EnumerateSubscriptions. One is attached to the list and one isn't. I fixed it by doing EnumerateSubscriptionsByList and passing the List GUID.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error. 
I was moving the workflow (wsp) from a site to another.

I changed name of the associated list (at my clients request) this was causing the error.
Everything worked when I changed the list name to the original named.
After updating back the list name, I re-uploaded the wsp and activated the solution and feature on site. The workflow is now working.